# Сколько "н" в слове "умерен(н)а" в данном конкретном предложении?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, удвоенные-буквы

*Стоимость обучения на подфакультетах в разных ВУЗах различна, но вполне умерен(н)а, а в некоторых случаях иностранцы могут быть полностью освобождены от нее.* Сколько "н" в слове "умерен(н)а" в данном конкретном предложении?

Comment: "Иностранцы могут быть полностью освобождены от **нее**". Освобождены от стоимости?

Comment: "В разных ВУЗах". Корректно: "в разных вузах".

Comment: Не просто обучение в вузах, а обучение на подфакультетах? А есть обучение не на подфакультетах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Стоимость обучения на педфакультетах в разных вузах различна, но вполне умеренна...**

1) Умеренный ― это прилагательное, поэтому в краткой форме сохраняются две буквы НН: **умеренный ― умеренна.**

Признаки прилагательного: обозначает качественный признак, имеет наречие степени, можно заменить прилагательным-синонимом.

Пример: Я нашла, что цена сия **умеренна,** чтоб купить народный покой. [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга третья. Ч. 2 (1934-1945)]

УМЕРЕННЫЙ, 1. Не слишком большой по размеру, количеству, силе и т.п., не выше среднего уровня, меры. У-ая плата. У. аппетит. У-ые морозы. Приобрести что-л. по умеренной цене. Есть мороженое в умеренном количестве. У-ые осадки.

2) **Краткое причастие  со значением признака по действию встречается крайне редко**.

УМЕРИТЬ, св. что. Ограничить, уменьшить величину, степень, силу проявления чего-л.

Пример: ... эта привычка должна быть оставлена или значительно **умерена** [Д. И. Иловайский. Начало Руси (1876)]